# How to check if any combination of two list items occurs in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I'm wondering if there is a way to check if any combination of more than two items from a list exists in another list?

```
list_1 = ['apple','soap','diet coke','banana','sweets','mash','fruit','veggies']

for string in lists:
    strings = string.split()
    print(strings)
```

SAMPLE OUTPUT for strings:

```
['today', 'i','bought','banana','but','forgot','soap', 'and','veggies']# this line should identify 'banana', 'soap' and 'veggies'
['maybe', 'there','are','more','sweets','left','later'] # this line should be ignored, because not more than 2 items of the list are in it 
['food', 'shopping','is','boring','and','i','hate','mash','with','veggies']# this line should identify 'mash' and 'veggies'
```

I know that by using this piece of code, I can at least check if any of the elements appear in strings:

```
  combinations = any(i in list_1 for i in strings)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [set intersection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) and check the resulting size:

```
s1 = set(list_1)

if len(s1.intersection(strings)) >= 2:
    #  do stuff
```

This will, however, not trigger if the same item occurs twice in `strings` which may or may not be what you desire. In that case, you could do something like:

```
if sum(s in s1 for s in strings) >= 2:
    # do stuff
```

Comment: thanks this worked great! Just out of interest - what would I have to do to trigger if the same item occurs twice? :-)

Comment: I added an approach for that case.

Comment: Set can not have duplicate items, so it wouldnt work.

Answer (score 1):

I was late apparently. This is basically [schwobaseggl's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61519409/3284713) wrapped as a function

```
mylist = ['apple','soap','diet coke','banana','sweets','mash','fruit','veggies']
mytest = ['today', 'i','bought','banana','but','forgot','soap', 'and','veggies']

def common_elements(mylist, mytest):

    common_elements = list(set(mylist).intersection(mytest))

    if len(common_elements)>2:
        return common_elements
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: i would return an empty list if none meet criteria in case he needs to check something with it

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
string = ['today', 'i','bought','banana','but','forgot','soap', 'and','veggies']
list_1 = ['apple','soap','diet coke','banana','sweets','mash','fruit','veggies']
n = 0
inv = []
for i in string:
    if i in list_1:
        inv.append(i)
        n += 1
if n >= 2:
    print(inv)
```

or you can put it into a define and make yourself a function:

```
def check(string,list_1):
    inv = []
    for i in string:
        if i in list_1:
            inv.append(i)
    if len(inv) >= 2:
        return inv
    else: return []

string = ['today', 'i','bought','banana','but','forgot','soap', 'and','veggies']
list_1 = ['apple','soap','diet coke','banana','sweets','mash','fruit','veggies']
print(check(string,list_1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this "hard-coded" way too

```
list1=['apple','soap','diet coke','banana','sweets','mash','fruit','veggies']
list2 = ['today', 'i','bought','banana','but','forgot','soap', 'and','veggies']
def check(list_1,list_2) :
    common = list()
    for i in list_1 :
        if i in list_2 :
            common.append(i)
    if len(common) >=2 :
        return common
    else :
        return "Less than two items are common"
try = check(list_1,list_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, you want to find out that 2 lists have more than 2 same element?

```
def intersection(list_one, list_two):
  intersection = set(list_one) & set(list_two)
  if len(list(intersection)) > 1:
    print(list(intersection))
  return False


a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [1, 8, 9, 10]
c = [1, 2, 5, 6]
intersection(a, b)  # return False
intersection(a, c)  # return [1, 2]
```